# When iterating a list in a python loop, why is returned element a tuple?

Tags: python, list, class, iterator, tuples

In looping though elements in a python list, I've discovered that it is returning single-valued tuples rather than the underlying values themselves.  I'm using Python 3.7.7 to run the following:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        """ class constructor """
        self.value = value,

    def __repr__(self):
        """ class repr method """
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(value={self.value!r})'

for val in [14, 20, 21, 48]:
    _myclass = MyClass(val)
    print(_myclass.value)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
(14,)
(20,)
(21,)
(48,)
```

It is clear that it is passing a single-element tuple to my class constructor instead of the underlying value from the list.  I can see the same behavior when I pass the the objects to the print statement:

```
for val in [14, 20, 21, 48]:
    _myclass = MyClass(val)
    print(_myclass)
```

Which produces:

```
MyClass(value=(14,))
MyClass(value=(20,))
MyClass(value=(21,))
MyClass(value=(48,))
```

This becomes a problem when I want to work with the value in my class -- in this case, treating it as the expected number (e.g., `if value < 30: value = 30`) would produce a TypeError.  How can I correct this?

Comment: `self.value = value,` The comma is the tuple constructor so you are saying self.value refers to a tuple that contains value

Comment: Writing `value,` is shorthand for `(value,)`, i.e. a one-element tuple.

Comment: Doh!  I see it now.  Rookie mistake on my part.  Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700951/unintentional-trailing-comma-that-creates-a-tuple

Answer (score 1):

you put `,` near the `self.value = value` remove it will fine. (Someone mentioned in the comment)

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        """ class constructor """
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        """ class repr method """
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(value={self.value!r})'

for val in [14, 20, 21, 48]:
    _myclass = MyClass(val)
    print(_myclass.value)
# output
# 14
# 20
# 21
# 48
```

Comment: Seems that the tuple (`self.value`) was created by mistake. Removing the trailing comma is probably a better idea...

Comment: yes I haven't seen it sorry

Comment: no harm: just update or remove your answer.

Comment: yeah I did thank you