# TypeError in Django: "float () argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple.'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

**Description:**

When attempting to access a specific page that relate to a cryptocurrency, in this case Dogecoin, I receive a TypeError in my Django application. "Field 'bought_price' expected a number but got (0.07314770668745041,)" reads the error notice. The traceback also states that the problem is with the float() function and that a tuple was used as the argument.

The passed value, however, is not a 'tuple'. It is a numpyfloat64 type, therefore I tried passing the same value after converting it to a float type in Python. Even if I provide the form a static value, the problem still occurs. `form.instance.bought_at = 45.66` results in the same issue.

Could anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it?

Here's the relevant code:

**Model Code:**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    coin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bought_price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    bought_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**View Code:**

```
ticker = yf.Ticker(symbols[pk])
price_arr = ticker.history(period='1d')['Close']
price = np.array(price_arr)[0]
```

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BuyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.coin = ticker.info['name'],
        form.instance.symbol = ticker.info['symbol'],
        form.instance.bought_price = price,
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('portfolio')
    else:
        form = BuyForm()
```

I appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: `form.instance.bought_price = price,` There is a comma at the end, so the value **is** a tuple...

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you! I know it was a silly mistake, but thanks!

Comment: There are a couple more places where you made the same mistake also.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I did change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the trailing comma turning `price` into a tuple.

```
        form.instance.bought_price = price,
```

should be

```
        form.instance.bought_price = price
```

The only difference is the comma at the end. The other assignment lines before and after probably need their commas removed as well.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700951/unintentional-trailing-comma-that-creates-a-tuple) for more.